# Nuxt3 - How do I use toast-ui editor on nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3, toast-ui-editor

Using Nuxt3 and [toast-ui Editor](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor/tree/master/apps/vue-editor).

plugins/tui-editor.client.ts

```
import '@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor-viewer'
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/vue-editor'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    return {
        provide: {
            editor: Editor,
        },
    }
})
```

components/DetailArea.client.vue

```
export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const { $editor } = useNuxtApp()
        const Editor = $editor
        console.log(Editor)    // {name: 'ToastuiEditor', mixins: Array(1), props: {…}, watch: {…}, mounted: ƒ, …}
    }
})
```

I want to use Editor as a component.

Second, I've tried it within components.

components/DetailArea.client.vue

```
import '@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor-viewer'
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/vue-editor'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const editor = new Editor({
            el: '#detail_viewer'
        })
    }
})
```

However, a 500 internal error occurred and a 'self is not defined' error message was seen.

Comment: that library is not compatible with Vue 3.  see the [github](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor/blob/master/apps/vue-editor/package.json#L28)

Comment: Oh... thank you. I will change this Wysiwyg editor